Is This Tree A Major Foundation Issue?
Recently took possession of an old rental in Wisconsin. Hoping to move in soon, but was surprised to see this large tree near the foundation:


Foundation is stone and mortar in this part of the house with a small crawlspace. I could possibly get in there, but it won't be easy. No indicators on the inside of the house near this wall of any major sloping or failure.
Assuming we will need the tree removed, but I'm thinking just leave the stump and not deal with it right now? That door is not the main entrance and is seldom used.

That tree is not growing near the foundation, it's growing on the foundation. You need to cut it. You can leave the stump. Removing that stump will require an excavator and quite possibly repairing the foundation.

at this point the tree is the foundation
